# GUI not updating until end of event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a gui that needs to be updated from a hardware device attached through a dll file and a textbox.  My problem is that gui is not updated until the end of the event and I need to show something pause and then show something else.  The hack of Application.DoWork didn't change anything.  Anyone have any suggestions?  Everything I was reading used either invoke or DoEvents and neither seem to change the behavior.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {

            App.myMainWindow.image1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();


        }
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this web page for beginning http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jieying/UsingProgressBarStatusBarandTimerControlsinVS.NET11282005021220AM/UsingProgressBarStatusBarandTimerControlsinVS.NET.aspx

Comment: @haywire: would you care to explain how this answered your question?

Answer (score 2):

You make the GUI thread sleep, obviously the GUI cannot be updated when its thread sleeps. Create a seperate thread and use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) to update UI-elements if you must, you can savely send that thread to sleep and your GUI will still respond.

**Edit:** `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();` you are sure about that WPF tag, aren't you?

Comment: If it's on the same thread wouldn't the GUI be updated before I cause it to sleep?  I did select a WPF application and not a Windows Form when starting.

Comment: That is what one would expect but that is not what happens, i do not know why though...

Answer (score 0):

I'd [use a backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and start it in the click handler.

This way the GUI will continue to be available and progress can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using timers as vittore had suggested.  This must be the way to do it since you cannot sleep the GUI thread during GUI event handlers.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    static Timer _timer;

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {

            this.image1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            this.image2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            _timer = new Timer(2000);
            _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
            _timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
        }
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
        {
            _timer.Enabled = false;
            this.image1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.image2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }));
    }
```